# RegEx for sun.org.mozilla.javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

May I know how to I create a name cleaning function for sun.org.mozilla.javascript?
I want to strip off invalid character(`~!@#$%^&*()-=+\|/?.>,<;:'"[{]}) in the file name and replace it with a space.

```
function f ()
  {
var x = jobdescription.replace(/\|&;\$%@"<>\(\)\+,/g, "");

return x;

  }

f ();
```

Comment: What is the question?  What is the problem with what you have so far?

Comment: The problem I have is that the software I'm using doesn't understand the script.  
  

javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: syntax error (<Unknown source>#3) in <Unknown source> at line number 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/[`~!@#$%^&*()\-=+\\|\/?.>,<;:'"[{\]}]+/g
```

Comment: @Jeno - Perhaps I'm not seeing what exactly it is you want to do here? The above regex matches all of those characters perfectly (tested in regexbuddy). I've no idea who marked it down, but an explanation as to why would have been a sensible thing to do, rather than just give it a negative vote and do nothing else

Comment: Thanks, It is working now. It seem that I ran into some datatype conversion problem.